# PHP preg_match - only allow alphanumeric strings and - _ characters

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I need the regex to check if a string only contains numbers, letters, hyphens or underscore

```
$string1 = "This is a string*";
$string2 = "this_is-a-string";

if(preg_match('******', $string1){
   echo "String 1 not acceptable acceptable";
   // String2 acceptable
}
```

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Code:

```
if(preg_match('/[^a-z_\-0-9]/i', $string))
{
  echo "not valid string";
}
```

Explanation:

- [] => character class definition
- ^ => negate the class
- a-z => chars from 'a' to 'z'
- _ => underscore
- - => hyphen '-' (You need to escape it)
- 0-9 => numbers (from zero to nine)

The 'i' modifier at the end of the regex is for 'case-insensitive' if you don't put that you will need to add the upper case characters in the code before by doing A-Z

Comment: this allow chinese character such as "你好" anyway to check against this as well?

Comment: @wlin you need to add `\x{4e00}-\x{9fa5}` to the charecter class definition, also add the `u` modifier to treat the string and pattern as UTF-8. It will look like this `/[^a-z_\-0-9\x{4e00}-\x{9fa5}]/ui` you can test it here: https://xrg.es/#1qvtb7n

Comment: @SERPRO your shared link https://xrg.es/#1qvtb7n    is not working.

Comment: @Kamlesh yes, tha domain doesn't work anymore but it was just an example you can try that regex in this URL https://regex101.com

Answer (score 19):

```
if(!preg_match('/^[\w-]+$/', $string1)) {
   echo "String 1 not acceptable acceptable";
   // String2 acceptable
}
```

Comment: can you explain what `w` is? I don't quite understand this

Comment: Alphanumeric characters plus "_" i.e. [A-Za-z0-9_]

Comment: @matino: You need to anchor your regex, unless it will match `a;b`

Comment: if someone still looking for answer `\w` includes `[a-z A-Z 0-9 _ ]`
that's why `\w\-` so it will be `[a-zA-Z0-9-_]`

Answer (score 6):

Here is one equivalent of the accepted answer for the UTF-8 world.

```
if (!preg_match('/^[\p{L}\p{N}_-]+$/u', $string)){
  //Disallowed Character In $string
}
```

Explanation:

- [] => character class definition
- p{L} => matches any kind of letter character from any language
- p{N} => matches any kind of numeric character
- _- => matches underscore and hyphen
- + => Quantifier — Matches between one to unlimited times (greedy)
- /u => Unicode modifier. Pattern strings are treated as UTF-16. Also
  causes escape sequences to match unicode characters

Note, that if the hyphen is the last character in the class definition it **does not need to be escaped**. If the dash appears elsewhere in the class definition it **needs to be escaped**, as it will be seen as a range character rather then a hyphen.

Comment: Not _exactly_ true in your description about when a hyphen needs to be escaped in a character class.  If the hyphen is at the start of the character class or immediately follows a character range (like `[0-9-a_]`), it will be treated literally.

Comment: this solution does not work on Turkish language characters. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

`\w\-` is probably the best but here just another alternative
Use `[:alnum:]`

```
if(!preg_match("/[^[:alnum:]\-_]/",$str)) echo "valid";
```

[demo1](https://3v4l.org/RW8Ou) | [demo2](https://regex101.com/r/FDgJZS/1)

Answer (score -1):

Why to use regex? PHP has some built in functionality to do that

```
<?php
    $valid_symbols = array('-', '_');
    $string1 = "This is a string*";
    $string2 = "this_is-a-string";

    if(preg_match('/\s/',$string1) || !ctype_alnum(str_replace($valid_symbols, '', $string1))) {
        echo "String 1 not acceptable acceptable";
    }
?>
```

`preg_match('/\s/',$username)` will check for blank space

`!ctype_alnum(str_replace($valid_symbols, '', $string1))` will check for valid_symbols

Comment: You still used regex so your solution makes no sense