# How to use preg_match to only allow strings containing alphabetic and numeric characters?

Tags: php, regex

I need a regex to accept only strings that contain both alphabetic and numeric characters. For example:

```
ABCDEF: wrong 
123456: wrong
!##$%@.: wrong
ABCD123!@$: wrong
ABC12389IKEIIJ29: **correct**
```

How can I do it with PHP?

Comment: Have you tried something or did some research ?

Comment: yes but i failed so i posted here

Comment: The first two rows are examples of alphanumeric characters, but they both fail the test that you are looking for. Why?

Comment: @AshishSrivastava Doesn't matter, just post your attempt here, so we can show you where the mistake is and what you have to change to get it working

Comment: If you have done some research and made some attempts, please show what you've done along with what is not working.

Comment: @halfer I'm guessing because they need to have BOTH alpha and numeric chars, not all from just one class.

Comment: i want the text to contain both nos. and english alphabets. so the last eg. is correct and others are rong @halfer

Comment: Right @Ashish. The word "alphanumeric" generally means alpha **or** numeric, not that a string must contain alphabetic and numeric characters.

Comment: alphanumeric:
    consisting of or using both letters and numerals.

Comment: We're all kind of waiting on what you've tried...

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP preg\_match - only allow alphanumeric strings and - \_ characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7753365/php-preg-match-only-allow-alphanumeric-strings-and-characters)

Comment: No, definitely not a duplicate of that question.

Comment: I agree with the several requests for a prior attempt, in particular because ["gimme a regex" questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285733/472495) are posted here a great deal. Most readers really do want to help, but showing what you've tried demonstrates that you really have looked at the manual, and really have spent some time and effort on the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
preg_match('/^[0-9A-Z]*([0-9][A-Z]|[A-Z][0-9])[0-9A-Z]*$/', $subject);
```

If you want to allow small and capital letters, add an `i` at the end of the pattern string.

Explanation:

`[0-9][A-Z]` matches one digit followed by one capital letter

`[A-Z][0-9]` matches one capital letter followed by one digit

`([0-9][A-Z]|[A-Z][0-9])` matches one of these two sequences

`[0-9A-Z]*` matches 0-n digits and/or capital letters

The idea is: A string which contains both (and only), letters and numbers, has at least one subsequence where a letter follows a digit or a digit follows a letter. All the other characters (preceding and following) have to be digits or letters.

Comment: A great answer, though it's worth bearing in mind some people here tend to refrain from providing a whole answer where no effort has been shown.

Answer (score 0):

I feel the most professional and comprehensible way of doing this is to declare two lookaheads which individually demand a certain range of characters, then match one or more characters that satisfy both sets of whitelisted characters -- of course, all of this logic needs to be nested inside of start of string and end of string anchors.

I'll demonstrate with `preg_grep()` applied to an array of test strings, but you can use the same pattern with `preg_match()` on a single string.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/ldnsL))

```
$tests = [
    'ABCDEF',
    '123456',
    '9Z',
    '!##$%@.',
    'ABCD123!@$',
    'ABC12389IKEIIJ29',
];

var_export(
    preg_grep(
        '~^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)[A-Z\d]+$~',
        $tests
    )
);
```

Output: (array of qualifying strings)

```
array (
  2 => '9Z',
  5 => 'ABC12389IKEIIJ29',
)
```