# Compare username to regular expression with PHP

Tags: php, regex

I've never used regular expressions before and did some research on how to allow my username field only `alphanumeric characters, dashes, dots, and underscores`. I have the following expression but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
$string = "Joe_Scotto";

if (!preg_match('[a-zA-Z0-9_-.]', $string)) {
    echo "Does not match Regex";
} else {
    echo "Matches";
}
```

I want the statement to return true if it is following the "guidelines" and false if the username contains something other than what I specified it should contain. Any help would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
$string = "Joe_Scotto";

if (!preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9_.]+$/', $string)) {
    echo "Does not match Regex";
} else {
    echo "Matches";
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. My initial testing is showing me that it's working the way I intended.

Comment: If you could would you mind explaining how this works? Thanks.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1330693/validate-username-as-alphanumeric-with-underscores and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7753365/php-preg-match-only-allow-alphanumeric-strings-and-characters

Answer (score 3):

You match only a single character. Try this:

```
$string = "Joe_Scotto";

if (!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+$/', $string)) {
    echo "Does not match Regex";
} else {
    echo "Matches";
}
```

The `+` sign says: match 1 or more characters defined directly before the `+` (`*` is the same but matches 0 or more characters).
Also the separators '/' (or any other separator characters) are required.
And in character classes, it is better to place the `-` sign to the end, else it could be misinterpreted as range from `_` to `.`
And add `^` at the beginning (this means: match from the beginning of the input) and `$` to the end (this means: match to the end of the input). Else, also a part of the string would match.

Comment: `Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: range out of order in character class at offset 12 in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/projects/g/test.php on line 5`

Comment: If for example I set `$string` to `Joe^Scotto` it will still return `Matches`. I'm trying to make it so that any character other than `alphanumeric, -, _, .` will make it return `Does not match Regex`

Comment: @JoeScotto: i added the correction to my answer; the characters `^` and `$` must be added to the regex

Comment: By the way: there is a nice online regex tester which can help designing regex patterns: https://regex101.com

Answer (score 1):

You should use something like that http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/ern

```
$string = 'John_Buss';

if (preg_match('/[A-z0-9_\-.]+/', $string)) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Make sure to add `/` delimiter character at the start and the end of your regex

Make sure to use `\` escape character before `-`

Make sure to add `+` character quantifier